# Does space cause matter to move in a 3D fashion, or, does the movement of matter in a 3D fashion cause space to appear 3D?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, spacetime-dimensions, elementary-particles

What is the mechanism that allows matter (elementary particles) to move with three degrees of dimensional freedom of movement but no more or less? I know it's not a question that has been discussed in textbooks, but, I'd be interested in knowing other people's ideas on the subject. I want to know about any theories concerning how matter (elementary particles) move with only three degrees of dimensional freedom of movement, or, if you believe space is responsible for limiting the movement of particles to only three degrees of dimensional freedom of movement, how does space, (which to me is just an idea, like distance or area, and not a physical entity), accomplish that feat? I know this problem has been ignored up to this point (or not even recognized as a problem worthy of investigation) but I think there may be some very interesting physics involved and discovering what that physics is could crystallize our current rather foggy thinking surrounding our ideas of the relationships between space, dimension, and matter. Or does dimensionality need no explanation, so we can continue to ignore it? To me it's the gorilla in the room of physics.

Comment: There are only three dimensions of space in mainstream physics. Is your question about string/M theory, where there are more? If so, look up open & closed strings. If in reference to the fourth dimension you meant "why is time travel hard?", look up special relativity's metric signature.

Comment: I know there are only three dimensions of space dealt with in mainstream physics, but in mathematics there are an infinite number of possible space dimensions. What limits our real world particles to movement in only three of the possible infinite number of space dimensions?

Comment: So is your real question why there is a finite number, $3$, of dimensions of space? If you edit that into your question, it might be taken off hold, which is important because it's a question that's hard to answer in comments. Mind you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropic_principle#Dimensions_of_spacetime

Comment: You should check out the anthropic principle. Otherwise space is 3 D. Since matter can only move in space( it moves in time too but only in 1 direction), it can move in 3 directions since it has *only 3 dimensions to move in. (You should out the anthropic principle to know why space has 3 dimensions and time has 1 dimensions)

Comment: @physics2000  I read the Wikipedia article on the anthropic principle. It doesn't really apply to my question. I'm starting to see that this is a psychological problem more than a physics problem. The concept of space causing matter to move in a 3D fashion is at the core of many people's world view and will not easily be dislodged.

Comment: Recently in condensed matter theory there are models whose charges have mobility constrained to some linear subspace, eg. https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11044